# How do I get Error Number and Message from exception from requests.exceptions.ConnectionError

Tags: python, exception

When I do this:

```
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
    print 'CE: ' + str( err )
    print 'T: ' + str( type( err ))
    print err.message
```

It prints:

```
CE: ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
T: (class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError')
('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I want to get the error and the message as separate items.

```
errCode = err[1][0]
errMsg = err[1][1]
```

I thought this was originally a Tuple but it seams to be a class.  I can't find the class documented with what member functions that it might have.  Is there a way to get those two components?

Comment: `print(dir(err))`

Comment: How about the error message.  I'll try what you gave me.

Comment: Have you tried `err.message`?

Comment: Oh... that wasn't an answer... I'm fairly new to Python.  It appears that it prints out a Class description but I'm not sure how to use that.

Comment: Ummm check my original code ;) .  It prints the entire object.  I want to only pull out each component.  AKA.  The error ID 54 as one variable and Connection reset by peer' as the other variable.

Comment: If you are looking for the message and error number and don't find `message` and `errno` interesting in the output of `dir()` I suggest reading the docs for the package.

Comment: The docs for the package do not include this detail and I've never used dir(object) before so I didn't know HOW to implement your idea.  Since then I've been experimenting and it appears I can use the names directly.  Unfortunately err.errno contains None.  So other fields are also not helpful.  errno: None strerror: None args: (ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer')),) Request: None
args: <PreparedRequest [PUT]>.  This leaves me with my original question.  How do I get the error number and message out separately.

Comment: BTW:  This is what the docs say:  exception requests.ConnectionError(*args, **kwargs)[source]
#A Connection error occurred.

Comment: Please guys... not getting this to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

OK... after lots of effort.  Haven't worked with Python much.  I have found this answer. Not sure if it is the best answer but here I go.  I found that ConnectionError did not fill in the err.errno field and err.message had a string that looked like this:

```
('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Unfortunately, that string didn't behave correctly. The code below works.

```
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
    converted = tuple(err.args[0])[1]
    errNum = convert[0]
    errStr = convert[1]
```

Now I have the error number and message from the exception.  If you guys can think of a better way to do this let me know.  Thanks!